# Can I ensure that this lambda function is called only once per interval for multiple subscribers?

Tags: .net, xna, system.reactive

I am converting an XNA poll-based input to an Observable-based input. Here, the GetPressedKeys() method returns an enumerable of enum Keys, every 20 milliseconds:

```
Observable.Generate(
    Enumerable.Empty<Keys>(),
    pressed => true,
    pressed => Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys(),
    pressed => pressed,
    pressed => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20),
    scheduler
).DistinctUntilChanged();
```

My problem is that this is done for every subscriber. I understand that Rx uses lazy evaluation, but I would like to somehow restrict this hot observable to execute the GetPressedKeys() function only once per interval, even when there are more than one subscriber. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do this via Publish:

```
thatObservable = thatObservable.Publish().Refcount();
```

Comment: Great, thanks (sorry for the slow accept) - for anyone else with a similar question, check out [this link](http://northhorizon.net/2011/sharing-in-rx/)